# Save user in mongodb Schema node.js without some keys

Tags: node.js, mongodb, firebase, authentication

I'm stuck trying to save a user in MongoDB. I have a user sign up form in my website which is authenticated by Firebase, but in order to have the personal data of the user in my own database I save it in my MongoDB schema of users.

I have problems figuring out the best possible way about actually saving my users. I was thinking to create two schemas, one for the users login data such as email, firebase_uid and provider, and another one for the personal data of the user (dob, street...).

Eventually, my approach was to have only one with all the data, but I don't know if it is a good practice to have only one. Is it possible to save a document without some of the keys on it if I only have one schema?

Thanks and please give me all tips you considered. :)

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
  uid: { type: String, required: true },
  username: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, trim: true, unique: true },
  img: { type: String, trim: true },
  provider: { type: String, trim: true },
  name: { type: String },
  surname: { type: String },
  doc_type: { type: String },
  num_doc: { type: String },
  gender: { type: String },
  dob: { type: Date },
  licence: { type: String },
  club: { type: String },
  street_number: { type: String },
  route: { type: String },
  administrative_area_level_1: { type: String },
  postal_code: { type: Number },
  country: { type: String },
  phone: { type: Number },
  emergency_contact: { type: String },
  emergency_phone: { type: Number },
  racket_brand: { type: String },
  handed: { type: String },
  backhand: { type: String },
  best_shot: { type: String },
  height: { type: Number },
  weight: { type: Number }
}, {
  timestamps: true // Add time in the database
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to save without them, noSQL databases like MongoDB are quite flexible with a lot of things. Nevertheless, you may want to read further about the topic as there could be other things to take into consideration. For starters:

https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php